# Can't be assigned scriptable object to state variable in game object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

As I said on head I can't assign my scobjecto to state variable.
I created 2 different scriptable object (with 2 different script)
(Their names "Starting State" and "Heaaad" as you see)

[Those are scriptable objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAkaJ.png)

And then I created 2 State variables to assign scriptable objects.

1. A State for my story.
2. A state for my head(title)

I can assign my "Starting State" object  to my "Starting State" state, but I can't assign my
"Heaad" object to "Head State" state. But ı did completely same thing with those objects.

["Heaaad" scriptable object gives this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuZfZ.png)

["Heaaad" scriptable object C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PwNv.png)

["Starting State" scriptable object C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxn8q.png)

[Those are States](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e67zo.png)

I don't understand what ı did wrong.

Thanks advance for your interest.
Sorry for any kind of mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of HeadHolderScoob doesnt match with the filename "HeadHolderSCOOB.cs"
Be sure the class is the same name in the file name (the capital letters in this case doesnt match)

Our welcome

Comment: I did. But didn't fix the problem ?

Comment: Yes is fixed but you need to delete the Heaaaad.asset and create again.
I run the test in my editor and is fixed

Comment: I  just deleted  and recreated asset but didn't be fixed   ? Yes, the warning is gone after ı did but the problem still stay

Comment: Can you send a screenshoot? The files and the script

Comment: Sorry Mate, It fixed the problem. My bad. Thanks for your asnwer ad interest